# how to access colors.xml without specifying color name or resource ID (R.color.name)

Tags: android, xml, colors

An XML file containing color names and hex codes is readily available to android programmers, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
 ...
 <color name="DarkBlue">#00008B</color>
 <color name="Navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="Black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

I can access a specific color using syntax such as:

```
TextView area1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.area);
area1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.Navy)));
```

or

```
 area1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("Navy"));
```

or

```
Resources res = getResources();  
int rcol = res.getColor(R.color.Navy);  
area1.setBackgroundColor(rcol);
```

How can I read in the entire xml file of colors into a String[] of color names AND an int[] of color resources (e.g., R.color.Navy), without having to specify each color name or resource ID?

Answer (score 6):

Using the reflection API it's fairly simple (i had a similar problem with drawable-ids not a long time ago), but a lots of more experienced users said, that "Reflection on dalvik is really slow" so BE WARNED!

```
//Get all the declared fields (data-members):
Field [] fields = R.color.class.getDeclaredFields();

//Create arrays for color names and values
String [] names = new String[fields.length];
int [] colors = new int [fields.length];

//iterate on the fields array, and get the needed values: 
try {
    for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        names [i] = fields[i].getName();
        colors [i] = fields[i].getInt(null);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    /* handle exception if you want to */ 
}
```

Then if you have those arrays, then you can create a Map from them for easier access:

```
Map<String, Integer> colors = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(int i=0; i<hexColors.length; i++) {
    colors.put(colorNames[i], hexColors[i]);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you, @bali182.  Mike R.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to move your color.xml file into the /asset directory. You will be obliged to parse the XML "by hand", and it won't be possible to use the R.color.* syntax. (unless you choose to duplicate the file)

Answer (score 0):

You could use introspection on `R.colors` to find out all field names and the associated values.

`R.colors.getClass().getFields()` will give you the list of all colors.

Using `getName()`on each field will provide you with the list of all color names and `getInt()` will give you the value of each color .

Comment: You should also consider a more refined mechanism to distinguish the names of the colors displayed to the user (they should be stored as stings strings.xml) and associate their values to a color (in colors.xml).